# number of paths of length $k$ in a random directed graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

Suppose we have a random $DAG(n, p)$. Here is how it's generated:

- Put n distinct nodes on a line, and connect each node in the $i$th order to any node after that; This would form a complete directed graph with $n$ nodes.
- Sample each edge with probability $p$.

The resulting graph will be directed, and acyclic.

The question is: what is the number of paths of length $\ell$ in a random $DAG(n, p)$?

**Note:** I know the answer for [an undirected graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424887/in-a-random-graph-of-n-vertices-what-is-the-expected-value-of-the-number-of-s).

Comment: Well, as is directed to the right, then the paths are just how to pick $l +1$ vertices from the $n$ vertices and each edge has prob $p$ so is not $\binom{n}{l +1}p^{l}$? Am i missing something?

Comment: @Phicar: I answered without looking at the comments, but yes, it's that simple (and my answer is essentially the same as your comment).

Comment: @quasi : No worries, thanks :) i thought i had misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the specified graph construction scheme, a path of length $k$ requires $k+1$ vertices, in ascending vertex number order.

It follows that there are exactly ${\large{\binom{n}{k+1}}}$ potential paths of length $k$.

For each such potential path, the probability that it's an *actual* path is $p^k$.

Therefore, the expected number of paths of length $k$ is ${\large{\binom{n}{k+1}}}p^k$.